# How to display Unknown on the view blade for date_of_birth in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'first_name',
               'last_name',
              'date_of_birth',

          ];

protected $dates = [
      'date_of_birth',
  ];

public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}

public function getDateOfBirthAttribute($input)
{
   return Carbon::parse($input)->format(config('app.date_format'));   
}
```

config/app.php

```
    'date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    'date_format_js' => 'dd/mm/yy',
```

view

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <p for="">: {{ $employee->date_of_birth }} </p>
 </div
```

Whenever the date_of_birth field is null in the database, the application displays today's date on the view blade for the date of birth:

```
04/08/2020
```

How do I display "Unknown" on the view blade for date_of_birth whenever the date_of_birth is null?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a null value, you'll need to check for `isset` rather than a boolean and branch based on the result:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
@if(isset($employee->date_of_birth))
    <p for="">: {{ $employee->date_of_birth }} </p>
@else
    <p for="">:Unknown</p>
@endif
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @if($employee->date_of_birth)
    <p for="">: {{ $employee->date_of_birth }} </p>
    @else
    <p for="">:Unknown</p>
    @endif
 </div
```